# Why is the accuracy for my Keras model always 0 when training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have built a simple Keras network:

```
import numpy as np;

from keras.models import Sequential;
from keras.layers import Dense,Activation;

data= np.genfromtxt("./kerastests/mydata.csv", delimiter=';')
x_target=data[:,29]
x_training=np.delete(data,6,axis=1)
x_training=np.delete(x_training,28,axis=1)

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20,activation='relu', input_dim=x_training.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(10,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1));

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_training, x_target)
```

From my source data, I have removed 2 columns, as you can see. One is a column that came with dates in a string format (in the dataset, besides it, I have a column for the day, another for the month, and another for the year, so I don't need that column) and the other column is the column I use as target for the model).

When I train this model I get this output:

```
32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 23s - loss: 13541942.0000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
800/816 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 11575466.0400 - acc: 0.0000e+00 
816/816 [==============================] - 1s - loss: 11536905.2353 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 2/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6794785.0000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5381360.4314 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 3/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6235184.0000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
800/816 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5199512.8700 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5192977.4216 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 4/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4680165.5000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
736/816 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5050110.3043 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5168771.5490 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 5/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5932391.0000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
768/816 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5198882.9167 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5159585.9020 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 6/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4488318.0000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
768/816 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5144843.8333 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5151492.1765 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 7/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6920405.0000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
800/816 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5139358.5000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5169839.2941 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 8/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3973038.7500 - acc: 0.0000e+00
672/816 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5183285.3690 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5141417.0000 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 9/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4969548.5000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
768/816 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5126550.1667 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5136524.5098 - acc: 0.0000e+00     
Epoch 10/10
 32/816 [>.............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6334703.5000 - acc: 0.0000e+00
768/816 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5197778.8229 - acc: 0.0000e+00
816/816 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 5141391.2059 - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Why is this happening? My data is a time series. I know that for time series people do not usually use `Dense` neurons, but it is just a test. What really tricks me is that accuracy is always 0. And, with other tests, I did even lose: gets to a "NAN" value.

Could anybody help here?

Comment: This issue should be every ML framework's FAQ and a warning message should be implemented.

Comment: Related: [What function defines accuracy in Keras when the loss is mean squared error (MSE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Your model seems to correspond to a regression model for the following reasons:

- You are using `linear` (the default one) as an activation function in the output layer (and `relu` in the layer before).
- Your loss is `loss='mean_squared_error'`.

However, the metric that you use- `metrics=['accuracy']` corresponds to a classification problem. If you want to do regression, remove `metrics=['accuracy']`. That is, use

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Here is a list of keras metrics for regression and classification (taken from [this blog post](http://machinelearningmastery.com/custom-metrics-deep-learning-keras-python/)):

> **Keras Regression Metrics**
>
> •Mean Squared Error: mean_squared_error, MSE or mse
>
> •Mean Absolute Error: mean_absolute_error, MAE, mae
>
> •Mean Absolute Percentage Error: mean_absolute_percentage_error, MAPE,
>   mape
>
> •Cosine Proximity: cosine_proximity, cosine
>
> **Keras Classification Metrics**
>
> •Binary Accuracy: binary_accuracy, acc
>
> •Categorical Accuracy: categorical_accuracy, acc
>
> •Sparse Categorical Accuracy: sparse_categorical_accuracy
>
> •Top k Categorical Accuracy: top_k_categorical_accuracy (requires you
>   specify a k parameter)
>
> •Sparse Top k Categorical Accuracy: sparse_top_k_categorical_accuracy
>   (requires you specify a k parameter)

Comment: Why do you say my output layer is using relu? From the sources it seems that if you don't specify anything there's no activation function. Am I missing anything? On the other hand, I can only use 'accuracy' when using a classification model? I'm a bit messed up at this time :)

Comment: @Notbad the default activation function is indeed appears to be linear. I updated my answer. However, that doesn't change the fact that as it currently written, the model corresponds to a regression problem. Regarding your second question, 'accuracy' indeed can be used only for classification (as it measures the percentage of the correct labels).

Comment: Here are a couple of links that I found helpful when trying to understand regression models, working with Keras. The explanations in this [Github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7947) issue are extremely useful to someone who is just getting started. Also, here is a 
[interesting SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665359/how-do-you-compute-accuracy-in-a-regression-model-after-rounding-predictions-to).

Answer (score 3):

Add following to get metrics:

```
   history = model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
   # OR
   history = model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
   history.history.keys()
   history.history
```

Comment: What is the point of adding the loss functions as a metric another time?

Comment: The metric allows you to view the accuracies. Without it you can only view the loss.

Comment: As implied by @bers, this is just redundant and meaningless for viewing purposes (both loss and metrics are reported, as can be easily seen from the outout posted by the OP above). This does not provide an answer to the question (the cause of which is adequately described in the accepted answer above).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out something that is very important and has been unfortunately neglected: `mean_squared_error` is **not** an **invalid** loss function for **classification**.

The mathematical properties of **cross_entropy** in conjunction with the assumptions of **mean_squared_error**(both of which I will not expand upon in this comment) make the latter inappropriate or **worse** than the **cross_entropy** when it comes to training on classification problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

while trying to solve the Titanic problem from kaggle, I forgot to fill the missing data from the Dataframe, because of which the missing data was filled with "nan".

The model threw a similar output

```
Epoch 1/50

891/891 [==============================] - 3s 3ms/step - loss: 9.8239 - acc: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 2/50

891/891 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 9.8231 - acc: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 3/50

891/891 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 9.8231 - acc: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 4/50

891/891 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 9.8231 - acc: 0.0000e+00

Epoch 5/50

891/891 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 9.8231 - acc: 0.0000e+00
```

Make sure you prepare your data before feeding it to the model.

In my case I had to do the following changes

```
dataset[['Age']] = dataset[['Age']].fillna(value=dataset[['Age']].mean())

dataset[['Fare']] = dataset[['Fare']].fillna(value=dataset[['Fare']].mean())

dataset[['Embarked']] = dataset[['Embarked']].fillna(value=dataset['Embarked'].value_counts().idxmax())
```

Comment: This does not address the issue, which, as pointed out in the accepted answer, comes from using accuracy in a *regression* setting, where it is not even defined (Titanic is a *classification* problem).