# Deep Learning Model to Predict Clicks from Keywords

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

[image]

I have a dataset of keywords and clicks.
I'm trying to build a model where it takes in a phrase of keyword ( not more than 5 words, eg: mechanical engineer ) and outputs a value (like clicks, eg: 56). I'm using the bag of words approach which resulted in about 40% accuracy which is not good enough. Can I get some opinions on what approach you would take to improve the accuracy?

Or perhaps my approach is wrong ?

After cleaning,
Here's my code:

```
words = []

for row in df['Keyword']:
    row = nltk.word_tokenize(row)
    for i in row:
        words.append(i)
words = sorted(list(set(words)))
training = []
for x in df['Keyword']:
    bag = []
    wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
    for w in words:
        if w in wrds:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)
    training.append(bag)

model = keras.Sequential()
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(858,))
x = layers.Embedding(858, 8, input_length=5)(inputs)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='my_model')
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                    batch_size=50,
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                   verbose = 1)
```

Here's a sample output of my X_train and Y_train.

X_train:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Y_train:

```
257.43
```

I have about 330k samples.

Any input in appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of `X_train` and `Y_train` inputs and targets in the question?
Also, how many examples do you have? (count of training data examples)

Comment: Try putting at least one dense layer in between the embedding layer and the output dense layer.

Comment: @NathanMcCoy I have added samples of X_train and Y_train and also the the number of samples

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I have added 2 Dense layers after the flatten.. the results are still the same

Comment: It's not obvious obvious from your sample how you transfer training to X_train and keywords to vector. That makes hard to reproduce situation you have. Can you please share your working code and part of your dataset? It would help answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a regression problem, not a classification problem.

What does the accuracy of 40% tell you? It tells you that in 40% of the test cases, the network did predict the exact number of clicks, in all the other cases, it did not, even if the number of clicks it predicted is around the right number of clicks. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775305/what-function-defines-accuracy-in-keras-when-the-loss-is-mean-squared-error-mse).

Instead, you should use the error as metric. It tells you how exactly your model can predict the number of clicks, whereas accuracy tells you how often your model predicted the exact number of clicks.

With this in mind, an accuracy of 40% seems pretty high. If you insist of accuracy as a metric, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665359/how-do-you-compute-accuracy-in-a-regression-model-after-rounding-predictions-to).

Comment: I understand that now. So taking mean squared error or mean absolute error or something along those lines would be a better measure of accuracy for my model.